# Creating new checkout step and getting JS error on checkout

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, javascript

> I've used the below tutorial from Magento 2 so that I can add a new
>   checkout step that influences another step, however after loading the
>   checkout I get a JS error (also below):
>
> Link to tutorial:
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_custom_checkbox.html

Console error:

```
    require.js:1895 GET https://my-ip/app/code/BusinessCheckout/CustomCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/single-checkbox net::ERR_ABORTED

Uncaught Error: Script error for: /app/code/BusinessCheckout/CustomCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/single-checkbox
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
```

The file structure is the same as the tutorial and here is my SomeProcessor.php:

```
    <?php
namespace BusinessCheckout\CustomCheckout\Block\Checkout;

class SomeProcessor
{
    /**
     * Checkout LayoutProcessor after process plugin.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout)
    {
        $shippingConfiguration = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];
        $billingConfiguration = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
        ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

        //Checks if shipping step available.
        if (isset($shippingConfiguration)) {
            $shippingConfiguration = $this->processAddress(
                $shippingConfiguration,
                'shippingAddress',
                [
                    'checkoutProvider',
                    'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street',
                    'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.city',
                    'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.country_id'
                ]
            );
        }

        //Checks if billing step available.
        if (isset($billingConfiguration)) {
            //Iterate over billing forms.
            foreach($billingConfiguration as $key => &$billingForm) {
                //Exclude not billing forms
                if (!strpos($key, '-form')) {
                    continue;
                }

                $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children'] = $this->processAddress(
                    $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children'],
                    $billingForm['dataScopePrefix'],
                    [
                        'checkoutProvider',
                        'checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.' . $key . '.form-fields.street',
                        'checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.' . $key . '.form-fields.city',
                        'checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.' . $key . '.form-fields.country_id'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Process provided address to contains checkbox and have trackable address fields.
     *
     * @param $addressFieldset - Address fieldset config.
     * @param $dataScope - data scope
     * @param $deps - list of dependencies
     * @return array
     */
    private function processAddress($addressFieldset, $dataScope, $deps)
    {
        //Creates checkbox.
        $addressFieldset['custom_checkbox'] = [
            'component' => '/app/code/BusinessCheckout/CustomCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/single-checkbox',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => $dataScope,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'prefer' => 'checkbox'
            ],
            'dataScope' => $dataScope . '.custom_checkbox',
            'deps' => $deps,
            'label' => __('Army Address'),
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'initialValue' => false,
            'sortOrder' => 10,
            'valueMap' => [
                'true' => true,
                'false' => false
            ]
        ];

        //Makes each address field label trackable.
        if (isset($addressFieldset['street']['children'])) {
            foreach($addressFieldset['street']['children'] as $key => $street) {
                $street['tracks']['label'] = true;
                //Remove .additional class. Can be removed, but style fix provided instead.
                $street['additionalClasses'] = '';
                $addressFieldset['street']['children'][$key] = $street;
            }
        }

        return $addressFieldset;
    }
}
?>
```

And my .js file:

```
    define([
    'vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\form\element\single-checkbox',
    'mage/translate'
], function (AbstractField, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return AbstractField.extend({
        defaults: {
            streetLabels: [$t('Company / Section / Unit'), $t('Post Sector Type'), $t('Post Sector')],
            modules: {
                street: '${ $.parentName }.street',
                city: '${ $.parentName }.city',
                country: '${ $.parentName }.country_id'
            }
        },

        updateStreetLabels: function () {
            if (this.value()) {
                this.street().elems.each(function (street, key) {
                    this.street().elems()[key].set('label', this.streetLabels[key]);
                }.bind(this));
            } else {
                this.street().elems.each(function (street, key) {
                    this.street().elems()[key].set('label', '');
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },

        updateCity: function () {
            if (this.value()) {
                this.city().value('Kyiv');
                this.city().disabled(true);
            } else {
                this.city().value('');
                this.city().disabled(false);
            }
        },

        updateCountry: function () {
            if (this.value()) {
                this.country().value('UA');
                this.country().disabled(true);
            } else {
                this.country().value('');
                this.country().disabled(false);
            }
        },

        onCheckedChanged: function () {
            this._super();
            this.updateStreetLabels();
            this.updateCity();
            this.updateCountry();
        }
    });
});
```

> I'm completely new to custom modules in Magento 2 so I may have it
>   laughably wrong. Anybody know what it could be that needs editing?
>
> Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
'component' => '/app/code/BusinessCheckout/CustomCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/single-checkbox',
```

to

```
'component' => "BusinessCheckout_CustomCheckout/js/single-checkbox"
```

And make sure the javascript file is located in you `Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/` folder.

Comment: Awesome, this worked! There was also an error in the .js file in the top it should have pointed to Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox instead. Thanks for the help :)